# Java abstract class - Should the instance variables be private or protected?

Tags: java, abstract

Should the instance variables be private or protected in java abstract class?

Simple question. I am trying to get more insight into the concept of abstraction in java.
Thanks!

Comment: It depends. It should be private if you want it private, and protected if you want it protected.

Comment: It depends on their use case but you want them to permissions to be as slim as possible. If you want the variable to be accessible by the instance class protected is the way to go. @JBNizet is right you want to lean as close to private as possible.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, go for non-final private variables. If your design calls for giving derived classes access to these variables, provide protected methods for accessing them.

Using protected variables creates maintenance liability in all classes, abstract or not. As soon as someone inherits from your abstract class, your protected variables become exposed as if they were public. Here are some reasons why this variables should be avoided:

- **Inheriting classes can change your variables at will** - this may go around variable validations set up by the abstract base class
- **Inheriting classes become dependent on variable names and types** - this locks in the design choice that you made when defining protected variables.

First rule does not apply to final variables because they cannot be changed, so the rule makes an exception for them. Second rule still applies, though, so you should be careful about defining protected variables, even in situations when they are final.

Comment: @JBNizet That's fair, thank you very much for the comment.

Comment: Wouldn't protected getters allow mutation by the derived classes? Or do you mean protected getters that return defensive copies?

Comment: @magnum_skrattar protected getters would allow mutation, but your code would stay in control of when the variable is mutated, to what value it is set, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If protected then this class and any subclasses may access the property. If private then only this class may access the property (it is not inherited). It depends on if you need to access them in any subclass.